# JSTree formatting issue - jstree-icon floating to the right

Tags: jstree

I am having a problem with JSTree.  I am using very basic examples but the `<ins class="jstree-icon">&nbsp;</ins>` are floated all the way over to the right hand side of the tree area.

[image]

Here is the JS that fires it off:

```
$('#adminMenuArea').jstree({
    "plugins" : ["html_data","ui","themes"]
});
```

Here is the HTML that I am using:

```
<div id="adminMenuArea">
    <ul>
        <li><a id='menu-4' href='menu-4'>About Us</a></li>

        <li>
            <a id='menu-6' href='menu-6'>Services</a><!-- in -->

            <ul>
                <li><a id='menu-7' href='menu-7'>Service 1</a></li>

                <li><a id='menu-8' href='menu-8'>Service 2</a></li>

                <li>
                    <a id='menu-9' href='menu-9'>Service 3</a><!-- in -->

                    <ul>
                        <li><a id='menu-18' href='menu-18'>Sub Services1</a></li>

                        <li><a id='menu-17' href='menu-17'>Sub Services 2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a id='menu-13' href='menu-13'>Employment</a></li>

        <li><a id='menu-14' href='menu-14'>Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Happens in multiple themes.  I have tested default and apple.

Comment: What is the doctype? If nothing, then place <!DOCTYPE html> at the top of the file.

Comment: Doctype is set to `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that all of the anchor tags `<a>` were floating left due to some other CSS in my system.